# Android ViewFlipper Animation (ViewPage)

Tags: android, animation, viewflipper

I got an application that uses ViewFlipper in order to do pagination, I would my pagination with a cool animation, and there is my problem. I want the animation to be synchronized with the move gesture. Pretty like this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2FRuFcBuPWc&feature=related, after 00m 40s.

So, how can I implement the animations to move along with the flip gesture? Sorry if it is a silly question, I'm new to animations.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** I wanted a looped ViewPager, was able to solve in this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/12965787/821054

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't understand what you were trying to do initially. I found what you were looking for, and got it successfully implemented in my app.

It's called a ViewPager.

Here's a [post about the ViewPager](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html).

And here's [some source code](http://code.google.com/p/viewpagerexample/).