# android viewpagerindicator, how to set the indicators count

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I'm using Jake Wharton's viewpagerindicator.  Because I want to use an infinite ViewPager, that means I only have 4 pages, but I set 400 pages for the pager.  I use currId%4 to get the correct content to the pager.  But now the question is, how can I set the indicators count by myself.  Now there are 400 indicators below the ViewPager, which I only need 4 of them.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can set this in your `FragmentPagerAdapter` inside `getCount()`:

```
 @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }
```

Comment: To do this, I can't get the loop ViewPager.  I want to loop the ViewPager, so I set a large number as the count of it.

Comment: you mean this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188011/how-to-make-a-viewpager-loop   To use this method, I still have to set 6 as the pages count, not four.  So the indicators number is still wrong.

Comment: You want to loop trough the Viewpager, therefore you are setting your count to 400? WHY? just implement a OnPageChangeListener() and set your ViewPager to the first item when scrolling trough the last.